# Display hierarchical subterms of custom taxonomy based on depth

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, hierarchical

There is the following hierarchical taxonomy structure of a specific post:

- Term A

  - SubTerm A.1
  - SubTerm A.2

    - SubTerm A.2.1
- Term B

  - SubTerm B.1

    - SubTerm B.1.1
    - SubTerm B.1.2

How to display

1. all parent terms (result: A, B)
2. all second level terms (result: A.1, A.2, B.1)
3. all third level terms (result: A.2.1, B.1.1, B.1.2)

Answer (score 1):

I love a good challenge!

The function here:

```
function get_post_categories_sorted ( $post_id ){

    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'category' );

    $sorted_terms = [];

    foreach( $terms as $term ){

        $depth = count( get_ancestors( $term->term_id, 'category' ) );

        if( ! array_key_exists( $depth, $sorted_terms ) ){
            $sorted_terms[$depth] = [];
        }

        $sorted_terms[$depth][] = $term;

    }

    return $sorted_terms;

}
```

will give you an array with the structure in the following image. `$sorted_terms[0]` contains the top level terms, `$sorted_terms[1]` all the second level term and so on.

[image: Sorted Terms for a given post]

It would definitely be worth using a cache or the transients API to store the data as it could get expensive with a lot of terms to sort through as the call to get_ancestors involves a call back to the database for each level it has to traverse back up the chain.

**EDIT**

You can use this something like the following:

```
$sorted_terms = get_post_categories_sorted( get_the_ID() );

foreach( $sorted_terms as $key => $level_items ){

    $number = $key + 1;

    echo sprintf( '<p>Level %s Categories</p>', $number );

    echo '<ul>';

        foreach( $level_items as $term ){
            echo sprintf( '<li>%s</li>', $term->name );
        }

    echo '</ul>';

}
```

**EDIT 2**

To just use a specific level, you can simplify the code above like this:

```
$sorted_terms = get_post_categories_sorted( get_the_ID() );

echo '<p>Level 1 Categories</p>';

echo '<ul>';
    //Change the 0 here to whatever level you need, 
    //just remember is is 0 based; IE the first level is 0, 2nd level is 1 etc.
    //If the number doesn't exist, PHP will throw an undefined index error.

    foreach( $sorted_items[0] as $term ){ 
        echo sprintf( '<li>%s</li>', $term->name );
    }

echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for reply. My questions above (1-3) are isolated questions. In your code I do not see a call of the term depth, therefore this is not what I need.

Comment: @Traveler in my code the term depth is found by `count( get_ancestors( $term->term_id, 'category' ) );` 

the top level terms (Question 1 in your question) would all be in `$sorted_terms[0]`

Second level (2 in your question) in `$sorted_terms[1]` 

Third level in `$sorted_terms[2]`

This would continue for as deep as the hierarchy goes. But would get very expensive for deep nesting.

Comment: You are right! But I have problems to make your code running in a template file. Something like `echo $sorted_terms[2]` is not working.

Comment: `$sorted_items[2]` has an array of term objects. You will have to loop over them to get a list or whatever HTML output you need them to be.

Comment: Sorry, I tried a lot, could not make it run. You may have a code example which can be embedded in template file to display for each level?

Comment: @Traveler I have added an edit to show basic usage of the function

Comment: Great code! It is listing the terms for each level of terms. How to amend the code to just display level 2 items (or level 1, or level 3) items? If this would work, you 100% solved my question.

Comment: @Traveler example added.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code works great! Just a small typo in your code, it is `$sorted_terms[0]` not `$sorted_items[0]`. The code is displaying the taxonomy terms as a string. Is it possible to produce links to the taxonomy item instead of a string?

Answer (score 1):

Found the easiest solution with the [get_the_terms() | Function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/). I really do not have a clue why the figures of level 2 (`$terms[2]`) and 3 (`$terms[1]`) are not in the correct order, but at least it is realized with a Wordpress function.

Level 1:

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'custom_taxonomy' );
echo $terms[0]->name;
?>
```

Level 2:

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'custom_taxonomy' );
echo $terms[2]->name;
?>
```

Level3:

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'custom_taxonomy' );
echo $terms[1]->name;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This [code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/244577/hierarchical-display-of-custom-taxonomy) is partially working, in this example displaying the terms of third level with `'depth'  => 3`. Unfortunately the parent terms are listed too, how is it possible to exclude the parent terms?

```
<?php function wpse244577_list_terms( $taxonomy, $separator = ', ' ) {        
    // Get the term IDs assigned to post.
    $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy, [ 'fields' => 'ids' ] );
    if ( ! empty( $post_terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {
        $terms = wp_list_categories( [
                'title_li'  => '',
                'style'     => 'none',
                'echo'      => false,
                'taxonomy'  => $taxonomy,
                'include'   => $post_terms,
                'separator' => $separator,
                'depth'  => 3,
        ] );
        $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( $separator, $separator, $terms ) ), ', ' );
        $terms = explode( $separator, $terms );
        $terms = array_reverse( $terms );
        $terms = implode( $separator, $terms );
        echo  $terms;
    }
} wpse244577_list_terms( 'custom_taxonomy' ); ?>
```

Comment: Can you show the code you tried using my function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution. The following function takes an array of arguments, with two possible keys:

- `taxonomy`: A string. The name of the Taxonomy.
- `level`: An int. Use 0 for the root elements, 1 for the children of the root elements, and so on.

It returns an array of `WP_Term` objects.

```php
function wpse_259499_get_subterms( $args = array() ) {
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, array( 'taxonomy' => 'category', 'level' => 0 ) );

    $subterms = get_transient( 'taxonomy-subterms-' . $args['taxonomy'] . '-' . $args['level'] );
    $terms_ids = array();

    if ( is_array( $subterms ) ) {
        return $subterms;
    }

    if ( 0 == $args['level'] ) {
        $terms = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => $args['taxonomy'],
            'get' => 'all',
            'orderby' => 'id',
            'fields' => 'id=>parent',
        ) );

        foreach ( $terms as $term_id => $parent ) {
            if ( ! $parent ) {
                $terms_ids[] = $term_id;
            }
        }
    } else if ( $hierarchy = _get_term_hierarchy( $args['taxonomy'] ) ) {
        $subterms_args = array( 'taxonomy' => $args['taxonomy'], 'level' => $args['level'] - 1 );

        foreach ( wpse_259499_get_subterms( $subterms_args ) as $term ) {
            if ( isset( $hierarchy[ $term->term_id ] ) ) {
                $terms_ids = array_merge( $terms_ids, $hierarchy[ $term->term_id ] );
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $terms_ids ) {
        $subterms = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => $args['taxonomy'],
            'get' => 'all',
            'include' => $terms_ids,
        ) );
    } else {
        $subterms = array();
    }

    set_transient( 'taxonomy-subterms-' . $args['taxonomy'] . '-' . $args['level'], $subterms, HOUR_IN_SECONDS );

    return $subterms;
}
```

**Note 1:** If you decide to rename the function, please note that the function is calling itself, so you need to change the name in the recursive call as well.

**Note 2:** The results are being stored in a transient for an hour. In order to get fresh results during development, you can add the following line at the beginning of the function:

```php
delete_transient( 'taxonomy-subterms-' . $args['taxonomy'] . '-' . $args['level'] );
```

You may also need to delete those transients every time a category in the taxonomy of interest is added, deleted or modified, if you want to have accurate results all the time.

### Example

The following code can be used in a template, to generate an unordered list of links to all terms in the selected level:

```php
<ul>
<?php foreach ( wpse_259499_get_subterms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'category', 'level' => 0 ) ) as $term ): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo esc_attr( get_term_link( $term ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```